# email filtered range as attachment through outlook

Tags: excel, vba, filter, outlook, office-automation

I have a master sheet in which column C has the names of employees, and I have data from Column A to Column AE, The number of rows changes from day to day.

I need a macro to send the rows to each employee as a separate attachment via email, for example: if raj has 50 rows, it must get emailed to him as a separate excel attachment with all the formats through outlook, then ram has 60, those 60 rows alone must be sent to him as a separate attachment.

The employee name in column C is the email id of each employee. there are more than 30 employees, so filtering and copying, and pasting into a new sheet and then attaching it to mail take a lot of time, please help me out.

I have been searching all over the internet but couldn't find any, so please help me.

Comment: See this thread. https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Comment: Hello, I want to send the rows for each person as excel workbook attachment and not as email body, can u help with that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Sheet for each employee
2. Use Vlookup() function in each sheet to pull the data from the master sheet for each employee
3. Use Macros in Excel to email each sheet to employee -

[you will find instructions halfway down this page](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/send-emails-outlook/)